# dynamic JQuery Dropdown with combobox

Tags: java, jquery, css

H all,
This is my modified Question i learn from help how ask Question in this forum
i am new in jquery want to create dynamic checkbox with dropdown.

Got example as follows

http://jsfiddle.net/evfnLn0x/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=evfnLn0xembedded/result,css,html,js

but i want display this on dynamic UI as where checkbox and item will get created dynamically

Things which i try 
html(which i have generated dynamically)

```
<div class="dropdown-check-list" id="list1" runat="server"> <span class="anchor">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;***** select ***** </span><ul class="items" id="items_234"><li id="379"><input id="chk_1504_379" type="checkbox" '="">mango </li><li id="476"><input id="chk_1504_476" type="checkbox" '="">apple </li></ul></div>
```

Js function use by me 
 var value = $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).find('div[id^="list1_"]');

```
$("#" + $(this).attr('id')).find('div[id^="list1_"]').each(function () {
    var checkList = $(this).attr('id')

    $("#" + $(this).attr('items')).find('div[id^="items_"]').children().each(function () {


    checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
        if (items.classList.contains('visible')) {
            items.classList.remove('visible');
            items.style.display = "none";
        }

        else {
            items.classList.add('visible');
            items.style.display = "block";
        }


    }

    items.onblur = function (evt) {
        items.classList.remove('visible');
    }


});
```

});

CSS:same as example
Please help
Regards

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @PeterBons  is it clear now for you?

Comment: This mvc application is also running in Service Fabric? If not, how and where it is hosted

Comment: @PeterBons yes mvc application is also in same solution

Comment: And the mvc app is hosted as a stateless service as well? If you take a look at the dashboard of Azure Service Fabric, how many services do you see? Can you post a screenshot of the Azure Service Fabric Dashboard?

Comment: @PeterBons no mvc app is not hosted as stateless service on azure service fabric dashboard i am able to see only one service .

Comment: You have to deploy the mvc application somewhere like on an azure website. It won't show up  on the azure service fabric dashboard if it is not deployed to the cluster.

Comment: @PeterBons  but how i can deploy mvc UI on cluster ? i deploye services like right click on  webapi project-> publish    and its done                                               
 so i try same for mvc web UI but it is giving different option which asking some azure account

Comment: You can't. You can only host service fabric services on the cluster. If the mvc app is .net core as well you can host it in a stateless service, otherwise you have to deploy it to an azure website.

Comment: @PeterBons so i need to create UI in services only ? like as add->new project-> service fabric-> webapi->and add UI code in another service so both service can take each other? is these right approach ?

Comment: Yes, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend). Or deploy the web app to an azure website and connect from there to the apis running on the cluster, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#connections-from-external-clients)

Comment: @PeterBons thanks for all explanation,example and reference.